# Disable a checkbox in spring and pass the checked value to controller

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

Hello I have to disable checkbox in spring html form and pass the checked value to controller. I use the below code, but the problem is that I am not able to pass the checked value to controller when the disabled attribute is set to true

```
<form:checkbox path="agreementCats" disabled="true" value="${x.value}" class="category-checkboxes" id="agreementCat-cb-${i.index}" /><label class="control-label" for="agreementCat-cb-${i.index}">&nbsp;${x.label}</label>
<form:hidden path="agreementCats" value="${x.value}" />
```

The above code sends all the values to controller. Please help!!

Comment: If you want to make the checkbox read-only, you can specify `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: Sorry was away for a couple of days, I tried readonly= "true" but I can still check the checkboxes. Looks like only disabled="true" works for checkbox :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in HTML have two tag with similar meaning but different context is Disabled and ReadOnly.

- **disabled**: Disabled the input in the form and the data isn't in form query.
- **readonly**: Omit the user UI interaction but the input is in form query.

Try use readonly tag instead disabled, I hope this help you.

**That solution works for all inputs except checkbox**... Checkbox can't use readonly, but you can do a little trick, is a dirt trick, but it can you help to not permit user touch check box.

If you know in server side what checkbox can be edited, try this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" <c:if test="condition">onclick="return false;"</c:if> ></input>
```

That code not permit user click the checkbox if the condition is true. Maybe with this can solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry was away for a couple of days, I tried readonly= "true" but I can still check the checkboxes. Looks like only disabled="true" works for checkbox :(

Comment: I search more and i found a solution, i gonna rework the solution

Comment: Yes thx so much, that seems to work for me though a bit dirt trick but its fine

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `disabled="true"` change it to `readonly= "true"` 
Disabled doesn't send a value if you insert but readonly does.

Comment: Sorry was away for a couple of days, I tried readonly= "true" but I can still check the checkboxes. Looks like only disabled="true" works for checkbox :(

Comment: @SharmisthaSinha maybe changing disabled="true" to disabled="disabled"or just disabled would work

Comment: No Disabled doesn't work. It does not send value to server. Thx a lot for your help and time.